# How can I safely eject USB disks in Openmediavault?

Tags: nas, usb-storage, smb

I have an external hard drive connected by usb to a PC with the **Openmediavault Nas system**. I'd like to be able to eject the drive out of the way and unplug it from power via a wifi plug when I'm not using it.

The bad thing is that to eject a disk in OMV you have to end the processes that are using it, and I use that disk to access it from Windows via SMB. When I want to eject it, I have to remove the **SMB** share and delete the shared folder on the drive, then it does let me eject it. This is torture to have to do it this way, in my previous **Synology** with a simple click you ejected the disk safely.

As I have been researching, in **OMV** it is impossible to eject the disk if there are shared folders. It seems crazy to me because an external drive is something portable that you can take anywhere. I do not understand how in OMV it is not possible to eject the disk without first deleting the shared folder or having to do the crazy thing of shutting down the server.

-Isn't there a way to automate this whole process in **OMV** so that it ejects the disk through a script or a command? Is there a program where you can do this? (without having to delete the shared folder).

-Are there ways for the drive to park its heads (or go into hibernation) so I can unplug it without damaging the drive?

-Can you create a script that does the whole process automatically? Create folder, add privileges to a user group, share it via **SMB**.